# Same batch job with different property files depending on launch

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a job definition in an xml:

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch
                           http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch/spring-batch-2.2.xsd">

    <import resource="../config/config.xml"/>
    <import resource="../config/common.xml"/>
    <context:property-placeholder order="0"
location="classpath:spring/batch/properties/ProcessAccountingMessages.properties"/>
    <!-- Batch job -->
    <batch:job id="processEventMessages" parent="abstractJob">
        <batch:step id="processEventMessagesStep" parent="abstractStep">
            <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="transactionManager">
                <batch:chunk reader="processEventMessagesReader"
                             processor="processEventMessagesProcessor"
                             writer="processEventMessagesWriter"
                             commit-interval="1" skip-limit="10">
                    <batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                        <batch:include class="com.ing.crs.frwk.exp.CRS2FunctionalException" />
                    </batch:skippable-exception-classes>
                </batch:chunk>
            </batch:tasklet>
        </batch:step>
    </batch:job>
    <!-- Beans -->
    <!-- Tasklets -->
    <!-- Readers -->
    <bean id="processEventMessagesReader"
          class="org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader" scope="step">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="queryString"
                  value="SELECT a.id FROM TempRawEventEntity a where a.integrationTryCounter > 0 and a.serviceId = '#{jobParameters['partition.key']}' and (a.typeError IS null or a.typeError = com.ing.crs.data.dbenum.EventIntegrationErrorCode.WAITING) order by a.id"/>
        <property name="transacted" value="false"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Proccessors -->
    <bean id="processEventMessagesProcessor"
          class="com.ing.crs.batch.spring.processevents.processor.ProcessEventProcessor" scope="step">
        <property name="sourceApplicationClassName" value="#{jobParameters['source.application.name']}"/>
    </bean>
    <!-- Writers -->
    <bean id="processEventMessagesWriter"
          class="com.ing.crs.batch.spring.common.writer.DummyWriter"/>
    <!-- Listeners -->
    <!-- Utils -->
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

I launch it like this:

```
        // Create application context based on the provided configuration.
        final ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(config);
        // Create job launcher. Uses fixed job launcher name at the moment!
        final JobLauncher jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean(JOB_LAUNCHER_NAME);
        // Create the job.
        final Job job = (Job) context.getBean(jobName);

        jobLauncher.run(job, jobParameters);
```

But now I'm in need of the exact same job definition, but the only difference is that I want to use different properties.

```
<context:property-placeholder order="0"
    location="classpath:spring/batch/properties/ProcessAccountingMessages.properties"/>
```

So how can I do that easily without having to create a new xml with the same job just for changing the line with the property placeholder? I also don't want to use jobParameters for this. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend using bean profiles for this.  Using a profile for each version of the properties you want to use would allow you to specify which one to use at runtime.   You can read more about bean profiles here: http://spring.io/blog/2011/02/11/spring-framework-3-1-m1-released/

Comment: Ok I have been playing around with it a bit and it seems to be the best solution to do it. Thanks.